# Como realizar un bucle for para una función que trabaja con Datas

Tags: python

Por gentileza, pido de su colaboración:

Tengo una funcion que calcula datos solares (azimith y zenith) usando informaciones ingresadas, en este caso **when, location**

**1 EXPLICACIÓN DE LA FUNCION**

La función tiene la siguiente logica:

```
def sunpos(when, location, refraction):

***Aqui realiza muchos calculos
y al final devuelve resultados***

Azimuth = resultado1
Zenith = resultado2
```

**location:** son las coordenadas en grados, por ejemplo (-25.645645,-31.54534)

**when:** aquí se ingresan informacion de datas (ano,mes,dia,hora,min,sec,UTC)

Por ejemplo, estos son lo unicos datos de entrada

```
#Coordenadas
location = (-25.645645,-31.54534)

#Data: 1 de Junio de 2018, 20:30h UTC -2
when = (2018, 6, 1, 20, 30, 0, -2)
```

Hasta aquí, creo haber expresado la idea.

**2 PROBLEMA QUE DEBO RESOLVER**

Ahora imaginen, que quiero obtener los resultados de `Azimuth` y `Zenith`, de los 365 días del año cada 30 minutos y guardar todos en una DataFrame, así:

```js
data               Azimuth   Zenith
2018-01-10 00:00    -36.54   198.09
2018-01-10 00:30    -38.64   190.08
2018-01-10 01:00    -35.74   188.01
................    ......   ......
```

Dicho esto, como implemento un bucle for para que haga eso automaticamente? considerando que tengo un DataFrame así:

```js
Ano   Mes Dia Hora Min
2018   1   1   0    0
2018   1   1   0    30
2018   1   1   1    0
2018   1   1   1    30
```

Desde ya, agradezco!

Comment: ¿Qué son "Datas" y un "DataFrame"? Es sencillo hacer lo que pides, pero no entiendo muy bien qué problema tienes.

Comment: @franmost un dataframe es un marco de trabajo, estos son un tipo de dato con el que trabaja pandas, sugiera que investigues antes de realizar un comentario

Comment: @Christian no he usado el marco de trabajo Pandas, no lo conocía. Pero sí, había investigado qué podría ser pero quería asegurarme antes de responder, ya que no había indicando por ningún sitio que lo usaba y antes de perder el tiempo con una respuesta genérica prefería averiguar si ese marco de trabajo iba a necesitar algo especial para el tratamiento de datos.

Comment: @franmost esta excelente, pero recuerda cuidar los comentarios, alguien podría pensar que *Dataframe* es una variable que no ha mostrado el usuario o un concepto no explicado :D

Comment: Cual es el dataframe que tienes? El primero o el último que muestras?

Comment: @Christian el DataFrame que tengo es el ultimo lo llamé 'df_when' que tiene las fechas e horas, con un total de 35 mil filas. Estoy intentando aplicar la respuesta de AnchovyCode, convirtiendo 'df_when' en un diccionario. Pero estoy tendiendo dificultad con la sintaxis 'd_list = df_when.to_dict('list')'

Comment: No es la mejor opción, puedo darte una respuesta pero no entiendo como obtienes el valor de `Azimuth` y  `Zenith`

Comment: @Christian Para ser honesto, estoy usando el código (función) que se encuentra disponible en este enlace: https://ichi.pro/es/posicion-de-python-sun-para-la-investigacion-y-la-energia-solar-134478336890743

Comment: Por lo que veo del código no hay una variable `Zenith` :/

Comment: @Christian hahaha, pido disculpas. No recordé que yo modifique el nombre de la variable. En el código de la pagina que envié, figura como `Elevation` o sea, solo para reafirmar `Elevation` = `Zenith` que básicamente es lo mismo, solo cambia la terminología

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es tan difícil como se cree y por cierto recuerda poner en tu pregunta el código completo de la función `sunpos`. Basta con hacer unas cuantas funciones y utilizar el método `apply()` para realizar lo que queremos. Empecemos recreando tu DataFrame:

```py
#realizamos la importaciones necesarias
import math
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

#recreamos el DataFrame
col = ["Ano","Mes","Dia","Hora","Min"]
data = [
    [2018,1,1,0,0,],
    [2018,1,1,0,30,],
    [2018,1,1,1,0,],
    [2018,1,1,1,30,]
]
df_when = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)
```

Esto nos generará tu DataFrame, ahora ya podemos trabajar. Para hacer todo un poco más ordenado, crearé otro DataFrame el cual contendrá los datos un poco más agrupado, para ser precisos contendrá:

**Columnas**

- `Fecha`: los valores estarán en forma `yyyy-m-d H:M:S`
- `latitud`: contendrá la latitud, será la misma para todos los valores (fechas)
- `longitud`: contendrá la longitud, será la misma para todos los valores (fechas)
- `UTC`: contendrá la zona horaria especificada en formato UTC, por conveniencia se les aplica a todos los valores (fechas) el formato *UTC-2*

Para esto creamos una función, la cual agrupará los datos de tu DataFrame para convertirlos a una fecha concisa, para ello utilizamos el módulo `datetime` una vez teniendo esto guardaremos en una lista el valor de la fecha y agregaremos la latitud, longitud y la zona horaria, que tu ya haías especificado cuales son.

```py
global df
df = []
def generate_df(x):
    global df
    #creamos la fecha 
    data_fecha = f"{x.Ano}/{x.Mes}/{x.Dia} {x.Hora}:{x.Min}:0" #{x.Hora if x.Hora>0 else 12}:{x.Min}0
    #convertimos a datetime
    fecha = datetime.strptime(data_fecha, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

    # separamos las variables
    lat, longitud = [-25.645645, -31.54534]
    zona = -2

    df.append([fecha, lat, longitud, zona])
    return x
```

Utilizamos la palabra `global` para decir que la variable será *global* y se puede acceder desde cualquier parte, esto por que *en secreto* estamos creando la estructura de un nuevo DataFrame, al final retornamos `x` la misma variable que recibimos por que no queremos modificar el DataFrame original y los datos obtenidos ya lo hemos agregado a la lista `df`.

La lista `df` es una lista de listas (o matriz) donde cada *sub-lista* representa una fila, ahora debemos convertir eso en un *DataFrame* real.

```py
df_when.apply(lambda x: generate_df(x), axis=1) #en secreto se crea otro dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=["Fecha","latitud","longitud","UTC"])
```

Si hacemos un `print(df)` obtendremos esto:

|  | Fecha | latitud | longitud | UTC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | -25.645645 | -31.54534 | -2 |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 00:30:00 | -25.645645 | -31.54534 | -2 |
| 2 | 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | -25.645645 | -31.54534 | -2 |
| 3 | 2018-01-01 01:30:00 | -25.645645 | -31.54534 | -2 |

Ahora lo único que tenemos que hacer es hacer las operaciones necesarias para obtener los valores de `Azimut` y `Zenith`, para ello tenemos que aplicar la función `sunpos()` (que tu tienes) pero antes debemos de *organizar* los datos correctamente para pasárselos de forma correcta a la función. Esto lo hacemos con otra función que se encargue de *tratar* a los datos y pasárselos bien a la función `sunpos`

```py
def calcular(data):
    #comprensión de lista para convertir a enteros
    fecha = [int(x) for x in datetime.strftime(data.Fecha, f"%Y %m %d %H %M %S").split()]
    when = fecha + [int(data.UTC)]
    location = (data.latitud, data.longitud)

    result = sunpos(when, location, True)
    return pd.Series(result)
```

Con `list(int(x) for x in datetime.strftime(data.Fecha, f"%Y %m %d %H %M %S").split())` estamos creando una lista pero con los datos transformados en tipo enteros, ya que el método `datetime.strftime()` devuelve un string, con `split()` simplemente separamos los datos para poder recorrerlos con la comprensión de lista. Luego a esa lista resultante le agregamos el valor de la zona horaria, eso lo almacenamos en la variable `when` que se vería asi: `[2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -2]` lo cual es el formato correcta para pasarle a la función `sunpos`, por último juntamos la latitud y longitud en una sola variable y ejecutamos la función `sunpos()`. EL resultado de dicha función lo almacenamos en una variable y ese resultado lo convertimos a una Serie de pandas, para que pueda agregarlo correctamente al DataFrame. Ahora solo debemos de recorrer el DataFrame usando el método `apply()`

```py
df[["Azimut","Zenith"]] = df.apply(lambda x: calcular(x),axis=1)
prrint(df)
```

Teniendo como resultado:

|  | Fecha | latitud | longitud | UTC | Azimut | Zenith |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | -25.645645 | -31.54534 | -2 | 182.92 | -41.30 |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 00:30:00 | -25.645645 | -31.54534 | -2 | 173.75 | -41.11 |
| 2 | 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | -25.645645 | -31.54534 | -2 | 164.83 | -39.85 |
| 3 | 2018-01-01 01:30:00 | -25.645645 | -31.54534 | -2 | 156.46 | -37.61 |

Por cierto recuerda definir la función `sunpos` antes de la función `calcular` para evitar problemas, si algo no te quedó claro o no te funciona puedes ver el código [aquí](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1X_wbwJ9bDW3NGURv8qiz3_TyzeAdjqXD?usp=sharing).

Comment: Recién vi su comentario, genial, le agradezco. Voy a testar ahora y confirmo el metodo

Comment: ok, avísame cualquier cosa

Comment: Su método, tiene total sentido. Es realmente lo que estoy buscando resolver. No obstante, la función `sunpos` debería readaptarla y me compliqué. No sé si es permitido, pero puedo compartir un cuaderno Jupyter temporariamente, para explicar mejor. Caso incumpla las leyes, lo eliminaré e intentaré explicar mejor la dificultad: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f9vEjuEn3JYyXVlvpukbKDSS7EChckDd?usp=sharing

Comment: En primer lugar no te funcionará por que el dataframe que tienes ahí no es igual al que muestras y segundo, me olvidé poner una línea de código >_<

Comment: Haha, si de hecho el DataFrame de datas, que coloque en la pregunta, era simplemente una descomposición del `datetime` que ya tenía, después vi que lo generaste de nuevo. Entonces consideré que no era necesario descomponerlo

Comment: eso dificulta un poco el trabajo, debías haber puesto tu DF normal y luego especificar lo que habías intentado

Comment: Ya hice un drop en el DF del google colab, igual al del ejemplo. Funcionó perfectamente jeje. Oye te agradezco bastante el tiempo que le dedicaste ayudarme, aprendí sobre funciones. Excelente respuesta, +10

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a por ello!

Partiendo de la base de que si traducimos el data frame a código quedaría algo así (una lista de diccionarios):

```
dataFrameExample = [
    {
        'ano':2018,
        'mes':1,
        'dia':1,
        'hora':0,
        'min':30
    },
    {
        'ano':2018,
        'mes':1,
        'dia':1,
        'hora':0,
        'min':30
    },
    {
        'ano':2018,
        'mes':1,
        'dia':1,
        'hora':0,
        'min':30
    },
    {
        'ano':2018,
        'mes':1,
        'dia':1,
        'hora':0,
        'min':30
    }
]
```

Lo que podemos hacer es iterar cada registro de la lista (que sería un registro de datos nuevos) e ir sacando sus valores por indices. Una vez tengamos los valores de cada dato, se los pasamos al argumento `when` de la función `sunpos()` en forma de tupla, de igual manera que lo haces actualmente (faltaría añadir la `location` y la `refraction` de donde te vienen en la llamada del `sunpos()`):

```
for data in dataFrameExample:
    when = (data['ano'], data['mes'], data['dia'], data['hora'], data['min'])
    sunpos(when)
```

o bien de otra forma sin usar la variable intermedia:

```
for data in dataFrameExample:
    sunpos((data['ano'], data['mes'], data['dia'], data['hora'], data['min']))
```

Dicho esto, aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcional de lo que he comentado y su salida, a ver si te sirve. Si tienes dudas o no era esto lo que preguntabas, comentame y buscamos alternativas.

```
dataFrameExample = [{'ano':2018,'mes':1,'dia':1,'hora':0,'min':30},{'ano':2018,'mes':1,'dia':1,'hora':0,'min':30},{'ano':2018,'mes':1,'dia':1,'hora':0,'min':30},{'ano':2018,'mes':1,'dia':1,'hora':0,'min':30}]

def sunpos(when, location, refraction):
    print(f'location -> {location}, refraction -> {refraction}')
    print(f'when {when}')

location = 'mock'
refraction = 'mock'

for data in dataFrameExample:
    when = (data['ano'],data['mes'],data['dia'],data['hora'],data['min'])
    sunpos(when, location, refraction)
```

Output:

```
location -> mock, refraction -> mock
when (2018, 1, 1, 0, 30)
location -> mock, refraction -> mock
when (2018, 1, 1, 0, 30)
location -> mock, refraction -> mock
when (2018, 1, 1, 0, 30)
location -> mock, refraction -> mock
when (2018, 1, 1, 0, 30)
```

Comment: Esto no es lo que se quiere, aquí solo estas sacando los datos e imprimiéndolos y esto no lo quiere el OP, por esa razón te he votado en contra

Comment: Buenas Christian, eres libre de valorarlo como consideres, gracias por tu aportación! Obviamente en el ejemplo solo se imprimen por pantalla, dado que por un lado, no dispongo del código de sunpos(), y por otro lado, como ya he comentado, es un ejemplo. En mi respuesta, he ilustrado como veo yo que puede resolver el apartado nº2 de la pregunta, es decir, la problemática que se expone, que es recorrer un DataFrame mediante un bucle For. Ahora, con las herramientas que se han proporcionado en la respuesta (conocimiento y contexto), va a poder ser capaz de adaptar el ejemplo a su caso particular

Comment: Siendo este ejemplo, totalmente funcional y probado con un Data Frame como el que comentaba el compañero en la pregunta. Dicho esto, gracias Christian por dar tu opinión!

Comment: No te preocupes, recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/477984/edit) tu respuesta para ir mejorándola

Comment: Buenas Christian, la verdad es que no entiendo el "No te preocupes", no he pedido disculpas en ningún momento (porque básicamente no hay nada de que disculparse). Gracias por animar a editar la respuesta, pero considero que está correcta como está. Un saludo!